# How to define key-binding with arguments for defun in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have a defun that conveniently adds / removes parentheses to marked expressions. (see code in the end)

As a neophyte in emacs Lisp, I only know how to make simple key-bindings without argument.

However, I believe the defun would be made more convenient if its key-binding could take two optional arguments to specify whether to add / remove `()`, `[]`, or `{}`

My current (simple) key-binding is as below, is there a trivial way to make it argument-taking as described?

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-( )") 'end-of-statement)
```

Appreciate any advice or direction tips!

(Code: by Istvan Chung)

```
(defun surround-with-parens ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (region-beginning))
    (insert "("))
  (goto-char (region-end))
  (insert ")"))

(defun delete-surrounded-parens ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((beginning (region-beginning))
        (end (region-end)))
    (cond ((not (eq (char-after beginning) ?\())
           (error "Character at region-begin is not an open-parenthesis"))
          ((not (eq (char-before end) ?\)))
           (error "Character at region-end is not a close-parenthesis"))
          ((save-excursion
             (goto-char beginning)
             (forward-sexp)
             (not (eq (point) end)))
           (error "Those parentheses are not matched"))
          (t (save-excursion
               (goto-char end)
               (delete-backward-char 1)
               (goto-char beginning)
               (delete-char 1))))))
```

Comment: For the question in general: `C-h f interactive RET`. For this specific use-case, there are existing libraries you could use, but I'll leave it for someone else to make a recommendation.

Comment: Sounds like you want 3 commands, one each for `()`, `{}`, and `[]`. You would define them all using a helper function. It is the helper function that accepts an argument to determine the type for the given command. (It could just accept a char or a char pair as argument: `(foo ?\( ?\))`, `(foo ?{ ?})`, and so on. You can use such a helper for any number of pairs of chars that have paren syntax.

Comment: The way you'll end up solving this also depends on how you would answer the following questions: Do you want to stick with a single key binding? If so, modify the `defun`s to insert different types of parentheses depending on the number of times you hit `C-u` before the actual key binding. Do you want to be able to have complete control over the type of delimiter that gets inserted? Modify the `defun`s to prompt you each time for the type of delimiter to insert/remove. Would you prefer separate key bindings over having to use `C-u` or being prompted? Define and bind some additional functions.

Comment: In any case, key bindings don't take arguments, the commands that they are bound to do. :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It seems these are the only options indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the question is for `surround-with-parens`, as `delete-surrounded-parens` is probably better off just guessing the parentheses used by itself.

I also assume that you are doing this for practice more so than for actually solving the problem. If you enable `electric-pair-mode` in recent Emacsen, configured pairs will wrap around any active region as your command does. But it's a good mid-level emacs lisp exercise.

As the comments noted, you have multiple options.

## Command Argument

A command can take arguments, as you asked for. Commands are no different from other lisp functions, except that they have an `interactive` spec. The `interactive` spec tells Emacs how to run the command when it is invoked with a key or via `M-x`.

Simple `(interactive)` will pass no arguments to the function. `(interactive "r")` will pass the beginning and end of the region as two arguments. Etc. You can read about the different options in `C-h f interactive`. You can even write lisp code to calculate the arguments there.

You could use `(interactive "cWrap with: ")`. This would prompt the user for a key, and pass the key to your function. For example, if the user types `(`, your function receives 40 as the argument, the character code for the opening parenthesis. `?\(` is 40 as well, and `(make-string 1 40)` returns `"("`. You'll have to create a map to figure out the closing parenthesis.

The drawback here is that you need to press two keys: The first to invoke the command, and then a key to specify the parenthesis to use.

## Multiple keys

You can also bind your command to different keys – for example, `C-M-(` and `C-M-[`. You can then use `this-single-command-keys` to get something that specifies the last key event. Sadly, this can be somewhat tricky to translate back to a key sequence. E.g. `C-M-(` returns `[201326632]`.

## Multiple commands

You could also just define one command per parenthesis type, all of which simply call a common function with arguments, and bind those commands to keys.

## `post-self-insert-hook`

Finally, you can use the same method as electric-indent-mode does: Add a function to `post-self-insert-hook` and decide based on `char-before` what you want to do.